# Prevent word wrap in angular handsontable

Tags: angularjs, word-wrap, handsontable

I'm using [ngHandsontable](https://github.com/handsontable/ngHandsontable) and trying to prevent word wrapping expanding my rows. I can see there is a table option wordWrap but this doesn't seem to work. I tried applying it in various ways:

ie add this in the settings object `wordWrap: false,` or add this class on the className `'htNoWrap'` or add this attribute on the table and the column `word-wrap=false`

```
                <hot-table hot-id="blotter" settings="{wordWrap: false, colHeaders: colHeaders, className: 'htCenter htNoWrap', contextMenu: ['row_above', 'row_below', 'remove_row']}" row-headers="false" min-spare-rows="minSpareRows" datarows="rows">

                        <!-- sort order? -->
                        <hot-column ng-repeat="column in columns" data="{{column.fieldName}}" title="::column.title" word-wrap="false">
                         </hot-column>

                    </hot-table>
```

**UPDATE:**

Actually i can see that using word-wrap="false" on the table directive is assing the htNoWrap class on all the TD in the table; however this isnt prevent the word wrapping pushing the drop-down caret onto the next row and expanding all the row.

```
.handsontable td.htNoWrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `wordWrap` from `settings` directly to the directive.
For example:

```
<hot-table settings="..." word-wrap="false" .. />
```

Comment: Did you remove `wordWrap` from `settings` in the `hot-table` directive? Try using `word-wrap="false"` only in column, you want to disable word wrapping.